# Transform records with duration to time-of-day table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a rather complex transformation in power query and due to performance reasons I need to push it back to a SQL Server backend. However I have troubles with implementing it - maybe you can help me with some clues on how to approach this problem.

I have a source table that has transactions with duration - ie. start and end timestamps, and these transactions can spread over multiple days. I would like to transform the table to a time-of-day scale to analyse how these transactions spread across the day from *0:00:00* to *23.59:59*.

The distribution is linear using time percentage.

So if I have a source table sample like this:

```
Record_ID   StartTime           StopTime           Measure
----------------------------------------------------------
   1        2020.06.06  9:45    2020.06.06 18:31      682
   2        2020.06.06  23:21   2020.06.07 10:51      543
   3        2020.06.06  16:38   2020.06.08 9:49     20921
```

The result would look like this:

```
Record_ID   StartTime           StopTime              Measure
--------------------------------------------------------------
   1        2020.06.06  9:45    2020.06.06  18:31       682
   2        2020.06.06  23:21   2020.06.06  23:59        30,5
   2        2020.06.07  0:00    2020.06.07  10:51       512,5
   3        2020.06.06  16:38   2020.06.06  23:59      3739,3
   3        2020.06.07  0:00    2020.06.07  23:59     12189,2
   3        2020.06.08  0:00    2020.06.08  9:49       4992,5
```

Some notes for the calculations:

1. For record 1 - no transformation is needed as this is not overlapping midnight
2. For record 2 - it overlaps one midnight, so two records are created, weighing based on minutes

   - 5.61% * 543 = 30.5
   - 94.39% * 543 = 512.5
3. For record 3 - it overlaps multiple midnights, so multiple records are created again based on minutes. If multiple days are covered, then I would need even more 0:00 - 23:59 type records to cover the whole duration

   - 17.87% * 20921 = 3739.3
   - 58,26% * 20921 = 12189.2
   - 23.86% * 20921 = 4992.5

Is there a pattern reference I could use? Is this possible to do in SQL? Is it possible to do it without loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select Record_ID, StartTime, endTime, Measure
      from t
      union all
      select record_id, convert(datetime, dateadd(day, 1, convert(date, StartTime))),
             endtime, measure
      from cte
      where datediff(day, starttime, endtime) > 0
     )
select cte.*,
       measure * (diff * 1.0 / sum(diff) over (partition by record_id)) as measure
from (select record_id, starttime,
             (case when datediff(day, starttime, endtime) = 0
                   then endtime
                   else dateadd(day, 1, convert(date, StartTime))
              end) as endtime,
             measure
      from cte
     ) cte cross apply
     (values (datediff(second, starttime, endtime))) v(diff);
```

Note that this registers the stoptime as the beginning of the following day, so there are no gaps.  That makes the allocation of measure more accurate.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bb4959af3b9c75e2de4333fa873859fa) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thank you, worked like a charm, although I still need to understand some bits.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to create a date dimensions / calendar table.
Then you can do something like this:

```
WITH cte_dates
as
(
    SELECT m.*,
        CASE WHEN m.StartTime < ad.TheDate THEN ad.theDate ELSE m.StartTime END as newStartTime , 
        CASE WHEN ad.theNextDay < m.StopTime THEN ad.theNextDay ELSE m.StopTime END as newStopTime

    FROM myTable m
    JOIN allDates ad
        ON ad.theDate between  cast(m.StartTime as date) and cast(m.StopTime as date)
)
SELECT cd.Record_ID,1.0 * datediff(MINUTE,cd.newStartTime , cd.newStopTime) / datediff(MINUTE,cd.StartTime,cd.StopTime)  * measure as measure
FROM cte_dates cd
```